# Why is scanf of a string saved to str while for the int it is being sent to the pointer of i?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I have this code:

```
char str [80];
int i;
printf ("Enter your family name: ");
scanf ("%79s",str);  
printf ("Enter your age: ");
scanf ("%d",&i);
```

Why is `scanf()` of a `string` saved to `str` while for the `int` it is being sent to the `pointer of i`?

Comment: You can't pass arrays through `...` and `scanf` uses `...`. So in both cases a pointer is passed.

Comment: C does not have a string type. And you cannot pass arrays to/from functions (this is not related to variadic arguments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf` needs to be passed the address of a variable in order to modify it.

When passing an array (a `char` array, in this case) to a function, the array decays into a pointer to the first element.

So passing `str` for the `%s` specifier is functionally the same as passing in `&str[0]`.

This also works for a `char *` which points to dynamically allocated memory:

```
char *str = malloc(80);
scanf ("%79s",str);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you notice properly, **both** the cases, you are passing a pointer.

In the case of an array, when passed as an argument to a function, an array *name* is essentially the pointer to the first element of the array.

Hence, `str` and `&str[0]` are the same.

As per the specification of the `%s` format specifier, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, *`fscanf()`* (*emphasis mine*)

> `s`
>  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.
>
> If no l length modifier is present, **the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array** large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically. [...]